# How do you use multiple tasks using Rake::TestTask?

Tags: ruby, testing, rake, minitest, rake-task

I am running Minitest with Rake and would like to have two separate Rake tasks.

I have added the following:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

task :default => [:test]
task :quick => [:unit]

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  puts 'within test task'
  t.libs.push 'specs'
  t.pattern = 'specs/*_spec.rb'
  ENV['STACK'] = 'stack1'
  puts "test stack #{ENV['STACK']}"
end


Rake::TestTask.new('unit') do |t|
  puts 'within unit task'
  t.libs.push 'specs'
  t.pattern = 'specs/*_unit.rb'
  ENV['STACK'] = 'stack2'
  puts "test stack #{ENV['STACK']}"
end
```

When I run `bundle exec rake quick` then I get this output:

```
within test task
test stack stack1
within unit task
test stack stack2
```

I did not expect both the tasks to run. How do I create and run two separate rake tasks? As it is now, the second one always overwrites the environment variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solve this issue by using `Rake::Task["task_name"].clear` like this:

```
task :test_task do
  Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
    puts 'within test task'
    t.libs.push 'specs'
    t.pattern = 'specs/*_spec.rb'
    ENV['STACK'] = 'stack1'
    puts "test stack #{ENV['STACK']}"
  end
end

task :unit_task do
  Rake::TestTask.new('unit') do |t|
    puts 'within unit task'
    t.libs.push 'specs'
    t.pattern = 'specs/*_unit.rb'
    ENV['STACK'] = 'stack2'
    puts "test stack #{ENV['STACK']}"
  end

end

task :test do
  Rake::Task["unit_task"].clear
  Rake::Task["test_task"].invoke
end

task :unit do
  Rake::Task["test_task"].clear
  Rake::Task["unit_task"].invoke
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Should it be `Rake::Task["db:test_task"].clear` or `Rake::Task["test"].clear`

Comment: Oops, in first edit I just tested with `namespace`... I have updated answer.

Comment: Comment: `Rake::Task["unit_task"]` can be written as `Rake::Task[:unit_task]`